# Java web application uses wrong controller

Tags: web-applications, tomcat8, netbeans-8

I downloaded some open source java web application project. For my purpose I created my own web application project and copied Web Pages source folder.
I created my own controllers in the new project - all have the same name but different package than the original project.

Now when I'm debugging, the code goes to the old controller in the original project rather than to the new.

I'm really confused. I run the debug on the new web project which has no dependency related to the old one.

I was looking for some settings that would set the controllers but didn't find any..

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 and Tomcat 8.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you close or remove from workspace the old project?

Comment: It still opens the other controller. I'm not sure where it is set which controller is used..